# Changing a variable's value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I've been trying to get my global variable's value to change upon running a function `test()`, but it doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why. I've tried declaring the variable outside the `$(document).ready` jQuery code and I've also tried using `window.testvar` to no avail. What could I be missing here, and how would I go about fixing this so the AJAX `success` function changes the value of `testvar`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    testvar = '';

    function test() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: { sessionUsername: $sessionUsername },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                testvar = '1';
                console.log(testvar);
            }
        })
    }

    test(); // logs '1'

    console.log(testvar); // logs nothing
};
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle showing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your console.log runs before the ajax succes function is executed..

You see, the ajax function is an asynchronous function, which means it runs out of the block sequence you are calling the function in.